# Will const-casting a const reference of a temporary cause undefined behavior?

Tags: c++

C++ allows the binding of a temporary to a const-reference, extending its lifetime. My question is: If I modify the object anyway by const-casting it, is this undefined behavior? Let's assume that my new reference will not outlive the original const-reference, so it will always point to a valid object in memory.

If it does invoke undefined behavior, why is that? The object lives on the stack, and if I can read it why cannot I modify it? I understand why this could be a bad idea as the temporary will be destroyed soon, but is it invalid C++? In my tests my program runs fine after modifying a temporary.

Comment: Who says it lives on the stack, and not, say, partly in registers? What if the compiler decides to assume that it won't be modified, and optimises accordingly?

Comment: It's possible to take the address of a const reference, so it has to have presence in memory, right? A temporary might not, in general, need to be in memory, but a temporary that has been bound to a const-reference needs to have an address.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to extend the lifetime of a temporary so that it's non const, just bind it to an rvalue reference. Don't do needless casting.

Comment: You are right for C++11, but what about previous standards without rvalue references? Plus, doesn't answer my question :)

Comment: @GeorgiosBitzes: Oli already answered the *literal* question for the case of a local reference. One can reason about the size and unpredictability of the object state and say that hey, for this object no compiler could predict the state or keep some part of that state in a register or... But UB is UB. The situation is different when the binding is to a formal argument of a function that returns the reference with const removed. For one, then there is no lifetime extension. And secondly, this was a not uncommon C++03 technique, so I'd be surprised it if were formally UB.